# Printing selected sections (odd, even)

Tags: macros, sectioning

I have an article-like document containing some info to be delivered to my class. I need half of the class to get only the odd-numbered sections and the other half, the even-numbered. Is there any function or macro that allow me to compile the file showing only selected sections following these criteria?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes you don't have explicit TeX conditionals in your text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\choice{}% for printing odd numbered sections
%\newcommand\choice{\unless}% for printing even numbered sections

\newcommand\startsection{%
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \choice\ifodd\value{section}%
  \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  \section
}
\let\stopsection\fi

\begin{document}

\startsection{This is odd}

\lipsum[2]

\stopsection

\startsection{This is even}

\lipsum[2]

\stopsection

\startsection{This is odd}

\lipsum[2]

\stopsection

\startsection{This is even}

\lipsum[2]

\stopsection

\startsection{This is odd}

\lipsum[2]

\stopsection

\startsection{This is even}

\lipsum[2]

\stopsection

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you switch the comment character, that is, you have

```
%\newcommand\choice{}% for printing odd numbered sections
\newcommand\choice{\unless}% for printing even numbered sections
```

the output will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `\nullfont`. However, this is challenging because of the number printed by the `\section`-command doesn't obey this.

There could be other things that wouldn't be hidden by this. The best way to hide something would be to use packages such as [`comment`](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment) and wrap it in an environment. And since you mentioned exercises, you could take a look at [`exercisebank`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank) to manage modular exercises (mixnmatch).

Anyway, I "hacked" the `\section` command it a little bit, but seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newif\ifprintodd%<- false by default
\let\oldSection\section
\def\hidesection{\nullfont\stepcounter{section}}
\newcommand\showsection[2][]{\normalfont\oldSection[#1]{#2}}
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
  % Check if current section is odd numbered
  \ifodd\thesection\relax%
      % Check if we should print it
      \ifprintodd\showsection[#1]{#2}\else\hidesection\fi
  \else%
      % Current section is even. Check if we should print it
      \ifprintodd\hidesection\else\showsection[#1]{#2}\fi
  \fi
 }
% Uncomment below to switch
% \printoddtrue
\begin{document}
    \section{First}This is shown when printoddfalse is called.\lipsum[1]
    \section{second}This is shown when printoddtrue is called\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```